# Aggregate feeds and grab image using Django

Tags: django, drupal, django-aggregation

Im currently have some website running Drupal, using `Feeds Image Grabber` module (`http://drupal.org/project/feeds_imagegrabber`)

Because I has started learning Django, I'm trying to look what tools available in Django which can give same functionality as my Drupal site:
-Feed aggregator
-Grab one image (largest image) from the source URL

Answer (score 0):

These links only address the first part of your question, not so much the image grabbing part:

- https://github.com/miracle2k/feedplatform  implements the core functionality of a feed aggregator
- http://birdhouse.org/blog/2009/10/20/generating-rss-mashups-from-django/ looks like a less general approach, re-using an application that powers the Django project website